# How to (automatically?) mark as spoiler a snippet of code in Discord?

Tags: discord

I am using a Discord server for teaching a programming course (using Java).
I expect my students to frequently post small snippets of their code in different textual channels, and I would like this code snippets to be spoiler (by default or not).

In Discord, it is possible to mark as spoiler part of a (non code snippet) message with `||this markup||` (double `|` before/after), or an entire message with `/spoiler rest of the line...` (see [reference](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022320632-Spoiler-Tags-) in Discord documentation), but none are compatible with the triple backticks ` markup to add code color formatting to a snippet of code.

So far, my ideas for a (non automatic) solution are to ask the students to always share their snippets of code:

- as attached files (which are not displayed by default, and can be marked as spoiler): that works but it forces to click the like, download the file, open it in an external editor, and keep going back and forth between this editor (e.g. gedit) and the Discord window, so it's not ideal,
- as non-formatted messages starting with `/spoiler`: that works but is not as pretty!,
- as direct private message to a professor, but by doing so they miss the possibility to be helped by their comrades (and in a course with hundreds of students and just a few professors, that's not ideal).

*Any ideas of how to do this in a simpler way?*

The last idea I had was to write a bot that automatically mark as spoiler every message starting with ```java (for instance), but apparently Discord bot *cannot* modify messages of other users...

Comment: When a code snippet is detected, automatically delete the user's post and repost it from the bot with spoiler enabled. Apply basic information such as who originally posted the message.

Comment: Hi @TinNguyen, thanks for the idea.
I started to write a bot, and I can successfully repost a message from the both, but I have the two following issues:
a) cannot delete the user's post (I do `await message.delete()` but it never works)
b) as in a user message, I cannot enable spoiler while keeping the code formatting. I have been able to remove the code formatting and add ||spoiler|| around the code, but when I click to reveal spoiler, the formatting is not present (and code is ugly).
Any ideas to fix these issues? Thanks!

Comment: you can't mark codeblocks as spoilers, even manually. it's a problem with discord (it seems they may have done it on purpose, but I still consider it a problem because it inconveniences me)